# What is the difference between Periodic and Non-Periodic Tx/Rx FIFO in USB?

Tags: usb, stm32, arm, usb-device, usb-host

I am trying to understand how the USB module works in the very low level on STM32F4 MCUs (ARM Cortex-M4 core). In the reference manual I read often the terms *Periodic* and *Non-Periodic Rx/Tx FIFO* (I am not sure if there is *periodic* and *non-periodic RxFIFO*), for example:

> Periodic TxFIFO empty interrupt mask
>   Nonperiodic TxFIFO empty interrupt mask
>   Receive FIFO nonempty interrupt mask

**I do not understand what does *periodic and non-periodic Tx/Rx FIFO* mean** (I do know what a FIFO is), I found no really helpful online resources about this. **Could someone explain these terms to me please? and are these terms only specific to *Tx* but not *Rx FIFOs*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference manual where you found these terms mentioned itself explains that the two types of FIFOs are used for different types of USB transfers, for example in section 34.12.2

> The host uses one transmit FIFO for all non-periodic (control and bulk) OUT transactions and one transmit FIFO for all periodic (isochronous and interrupt) OUT transactions.

Realistically you probably should not be looking at the hardware engine in this level of detail unless you have substantial USB expertise; for any normal use you would let an existing USB stack (from ST or someone else) handle it, and only worry about following the requirements/examples for integration and providing or claiming data with the appropriate APIs.  Getting this level of detail would tend to occur only if trying to write your own USB stack or if trying to de behind-the-scenes debugging of an unexpected incompatibility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for quoting from the reference manual, I basically have some essential USB understanding. I already thought (but was not sure) that periodic and non-periodic here refer to to those transfer types. So from what you wrote, are these two FIFO types applicable only for host mode? And are there only one type of Rx FIFO (no periodic and non-periodic)?

Comment: Take a look at the immediately preceding section of the reference manual.  And again, what *actual problem are you trying to solve here?*

Comment: Ok I will take a look on it. I am just trying to write a very basic USB stack to understand as far as possible what is going on here. I know it is not the easiest thing to do, but curiosity motivates me here.

Comment: Ok I skimmed the *OTG_FS* and *OTG_HS* chapters, now the idea is relatively clear. Thank you! Though, may I ask you to add few words about them to your answer so that it covers the whole question (I can also edit your answer to add the information).